# How can I find the level info (ground, walls, etc...) in the Mega Man 2 RAM and/or ROM?

Tags: lua, emulation, ram

I'm trying to find the RAM or ROM addresses of the game level information for the Mega Man 2 NES ROM in order to implement some Lua scripting using the FCEUX emulator. I need the level structure, not tile images. I've already used the available tools for RAM searching without success for this specific data (I could only find sprite data).

Comment: You're more likely to get help here if you ask "How do I find *X*" rather than "Where can I find *X*".  It's about learning, not doing work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want anyone to do work for me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it! :D

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRRyGJq-qwM (source included in the video description)

I had to read the ROM and use current stage ($2A) + current screen ($440) + scroll X ($1F) from RAM to figure out the exact position of current screen info. First stage is at $10 in rom, starting with solidity info. $510 stores the map layout itself. Each code in the map maps to 4 tile properties at the $10 region. Next level starts at $4010 , the next at $8010 and so on. [Rock5easily's editor](http://rock5easily.sakura.ne.jp/r2e.html) helped a lot to figure out the codes and addresses.